# String to Word Vector in R

Tags: string, r, text-mining, tm

There are 40 rows in my dataset and 3 attribute columns. Each row is a separate text document. I converted strings to separate terms using `TermdocumentMatrix()` function of `library(tm)`. But this functions is treating number of attribute columns as number of documents. Why is it so? Am I making some mistake?

Is there any attribute filter in R which is similar to weka's `StringToWordVector` filter? I want the result to be same as weka's `StringToWordVector` filter

Sample is shown below :

```
Title, Author, BookSummary

The Da Vinci Code, Dan Brown, Louvre curator and Priory of Sion Grand Master Jacques<br>
```

This sample is showing just 1 row.

I tried this code :-

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/RTextMining/dataset.csv")
corpus.tmp<-Corpus(VectorSource(data))
View(corpus.tmp)

corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp,removePunctuation)  
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

library(SnowballC)
corpus.tmp <- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stemDocument)

TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus.tmp)
```

Comment: Where's a reproducible example?  it's difficult to provide help when we don't know what the data looks like (pick 3 rows) or the code you're trying.  You can try `qdap`'s `?bag_o_words` function but it may not be fast enough for your needs.

Comment: Hi tyler rinker I have posted sample dataset.

Comment: @r4sn4, what is the expected result? I'm not familiar with weka.

Comment: @RichardScriven In addition to above code I applied weightTfIdf() function.So, the expected result should be like:-  No. of coulmns = No. of terms and No. of rows = No. of documents. Value in each cell = frequency of each term in the corresponding document.